# adding dynamic data to sublcassed QAbstractTableModel

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

for testing purposes a have function that asks for input and displays it in a `QListView`
[display data](https://gist.github.com/JosephCurvin/3964f1cb9371681adccb5688480549e5).
this works fine with one dim.data
I want to extend the script to display two-dimensional data

the incoming data should be inserted in the first row till column 3, and proceeds on the next rows (same operation) so the model contains the data in this form

```
 input_values = [[1,2],
                 [1,2]]....
```

so far I implemented that the input_data is added into the first row, but the script stops running before it starts adding the data into the second row. I just get this info

`Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)`

What is cousing this behavior and how to fix that ?

```
    def thread_data_add(self, data):
        if len(self.model.input_data[0]) <= 1:
            self.model.input_data[0].append(data)
            self.model.layoutChanged.emit()

        elif len(self.model.input_data[0]) > 1:
            self.model.input_data.append([])
            self.model.input_data[1].append(data) #crashes here !!! need crash report
            self.model.layoutChanged.emit()
```

full code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""


"""


import threading
import sys
import logging

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtCore as qtc
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg


class ViewModel(qtc.QAbstractTableModel):


    def __init__(self, input_data=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.input_data = input_data or [[]]
        #


    def data(self, index, role): # parameter index, role are needed !
        """

        :param index: Instance of QModelIndex Class  / set automatically
        Model indexes refer to items in models,
         contain all the information required to specify their locations in those models

        :param role: what type should be returned
        :return: data as a string
        """
        if role == qtc.Qt.DisplayRole:
            row = index.row()
            column = index.column()
            text = self.input_data[row][column] 
            return text



    def rowCount(self, index):
        return len(self.input_data)

    def columnCount(self, index):
        return len(self.input_data[0])


    def getData(self):
        print(self.input_data)
        # todo how to show list data





class MainWindow(qtw.QWidget):

    core_signal = qtc.pyqtSignal(str)


    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # View
        table_view = qtw.QTableView()
        self.model = ViewModel()
        table_view.setModel(self.model)

        # widgets
        self.start_thread_button = qtw.QPushButton("start Thread")
        self.test_button = qtw.QPushButton("display data")

        # layout
        qvboxlayout = qtw.QVBoxLayout()
        qvboxlayout.addWidget(table_view)

        qvboxlayout.addWidget(self.start_thread_button)
        qvboxlayout.addWidget(self.test_button)
        self.setLayout(qvboxlayout)
        self.show()


        # self.logger = self.default_logger()


        # function

        self.start_thread_button.clicked.connect(self.start)
        self.test_button.clicked.connect(self.model.getData)


    def lambda_thread_data_add(self, data):
        if len(self.model.input_data[0]) <= 1:
            self.model.input_data[0].append(data)
            self.model.layoutChanged.emit()
            # self.model.input_data.append([])
        elif len(self.model.input_data[0]) > 1:
            self.model.input_data.append([])
            self.model.input_data[1].append(data) #crashes here !!! need crash report
            self.model.layoutChanged.emit()



    def thread_data_add(self, data):
        if len(self.model.input_data[0]) <= 1:
            self.model.input_data[0].append(data)
            self.model.layoutChanged.emit()
            # self.model.input_data.append([])
        elif len(self.model.input_data[0]) > 1:
            self.model.input_data.append([])
            self.model.input_data[1].append(data) #crashes here !!! need crash report
            self.model.layoutChanged.emit()



    def start(self):
        # starts thread
        # Setting thread.daemon = True will allow the main program to exit before thread is killed.
        threading.Thread(target=self._execute, daemon=True).start()
        self.core_signal.connect(self.thread_data_add)


    def _execute(self):
        while True:
            user_input = input("type in: ")
            self.core_signal.emit(user_input) # transmit data


    def default_logger(self,level=logging.DEBUG, save_path='beispiel.log'):
    # create logger
        custom_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        custom_logger.setLevel(level)

        # was reingegeben werden soll
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s;%(message)s;%(filename)s;%(lineno)d', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        file_handler = logging.FileHandler(save_path)
        file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        custom_logger.addHandler(file_handler)

        stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        custom_logger.addHandler(stream_handler)

        return custom_logger

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Well, besides the fact that using shell input is not a very good idea for a GUI based program, clearly you have to add the data properly. In the way you're doing it, you are adding a *string* to a list, so the resulting list would be something like `[[1,2,3,4],
 [1,2,3,4], 'text', 'some other text']`; do a `print(self.model.input_data)` after `append()` and you'll see. So, the problem is that, obviously, when you try to read the contents in `data()` it will result in a serious problem. Find a better way to add the data and ensure that the columns in the "array" are always correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are getting is an IndexError since the data is not being added uniformly (whole row at a time), it is being added one column, or cell, at a time. As a result, when starting the next row with the 3rd input, there is no data for the 2nd column in that row yet. You don't necessarily have to change the way you are inserting data, just catch the error and supply an empty string or None value.

```
def data(self, index, role):
    if role == qtc.Qt.DisplayRole:
        try:
            text = self.input_data[index.row()][index.column()]
        except IndexError:
            text = None
        return text
```

Additionally, make sure you are accessing the correct index of `input_data` in `thread_data_add()`, which would be the last index [-1] since you are appending data.

```
def thread_data_add(self, data):
    if len(self.model.input_data[-1]) < 2:
        self.model.input_data[-1].append(data)
    else:
        self.model.input_data.append([data])
    self.model.layoutChanged.emit()
```

Comment: thanks works very well,  I don 't quite understand the reason behind the changes in the data method,  so after the first row is populated wich contains 4 columns, a second row is added,  data is been added into the first colum of the second row, and with try/except the empty columns of the second row are been populated first with None typ "data"  and then changed with the incoming data, correct ?

Comment: Yes that's right. And the reason the first row was not throwing an error with the first entry is because `columnCount()` returns the length of the first row, `len(self.input_data[0])`. If it had `return 2` instead then the very first data entry would have also resulted in an error.